# How to display individual resources with rolled up summary tasks?

Tags: ms-project, task-management

I’m trying to see if there’s a view that can display each individual’s assigned task, with rolled-up summary tasks. Right now I have my project set up with summary tasks (milestones) and sub-tasks underneath it, but when I switch to the resource usage view, I can see the different resources and each individual task assigned to that person. However, is there any way I can see these tasks under the person to be grouped by the summary tasks as well? I can't seem to find the right report or view to achieving that.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of MS-Project do you use as this is critical how to achieve this view ;-)